# How to configure Artifactory using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL?

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, artifactory

How would one configure PostgreSQL instead of [MySQL](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Running+Artifactory+on+MySQL) to run [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php)?

Comment: What version of Artifactory are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Artifactory 2 you can configure the datasource as per the instructions you reference, just do the equivalent for PostgreSQL (substituting for the equivalent values).

So modify $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties to uncomment (and modify )the line:

```
artifactory.jcr.configPath=repo/postgresql
```

Create the file

```
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/repo/postgresql/repo.xml
```

The repo.xml to use as a base is referenced in the article, or you can find it [here](http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/trunk/standalone/src/main/install/etc/repo/mysql/repo.xml)

You then need to set repo.xml's contents to match your database settings (extracted the relevant sections from the referenced file and modified what I can):

```
<!-- MySQL Filesystem -->
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
    <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:[your database URL]"/>
    <param name="user" value="artifactory_user"/>
    <param name="password" value="password"/>
    <!-- Leave this on "mysql", don't know how these apply for PostgreSQL -->
    <param name="schema" value="[postgresql??]"/>
    <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="rep_"/>
</FileSystem>

<!-- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore -->

<!-- MySQL Datastore -->
<DataStore class="org.artifactory.jcr.jackrabbit.ArtifactoryDbDataStoreImpl">
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:[your database URL]"/>
    <param name="tablePrefix" value=""/>
    <param name="user" value="artifactory_user"/>
    <param name="password" value="password"/>
    <param name="databaseType" value="postgresql"/>
    <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="512"/>
    <param name="maxConnections" value="15"/>
    <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true"/>
</DataStore>



    <!-- PostGreSQL Persistance Manager -->
    <PersistenceManager
            class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
        <param name="url"
               value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/artifactory?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
        <param name="user" value="artifactory_user"/>
        <param name="password" value="password"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
```

Remember to drop the [PostgreSQL jar](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) into the WEB-INF/lib directory, and as the instructions say, probably best to run this against a clean install.

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

The link to the repo.xml file is broken and not correct (because it point to mysql configuration).

To get the correct repo.xml file

1. Downloading the OSS version from the  [web site](http://www.jfrog.com/download.php).
2. extract it to a folder
3. look inside the extracted folder and go to /etc/repo 
   You have two possibilities for postgres : 
   A. filesystem-postgres/repo.xml 
   B. postgres/repo.xml
4. copy the folder A or B in your $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/repo/
5. edit username/password and database info into the **/repo.xml file you just copied according to your database configuration.

**NOTE:** remember that this will impact the change you did in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties (artifactory.jcr.configDir=filesystem-postgres OR artifactory.jcr.configDir=repo/postgresql)